# convert update query to linq with not in statement

Tags: sql, linq

My sql statement is

```
update Gallery set IsPublished = 0 where GalleryId not in ('1','2');
```

how to convert this into linq

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot UPDATE in a linq query. Your SELECT query can be something like:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2 }; // Assuming integers here
var galleriesToUpdate = context.Gallery
    .Where(g => !ids.contains(g.GalleryId)).ToList();
```

And then update them

```
foreach(var gallery in galleriesToUpdate) {
    gallery.IsPublished = 0;
}
```

And then save them using the context.

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```