# SQL not in - LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

**SQL**

```
select * from tempFinal where TypeId not in (13,14,15,51,52,55,59) -- Note: From Stored
```

**Current LINQ**

```
int LeaveExists = (from dt in db.LeaveDetails join
                 leavH in db.LeaveHeaders on dt.LeaveHeaderId equals leavH.LeaveHeaderId
                 where (leavH.LeaveTypeId != 55 && leavH.LeaveTypeId != 59 && . . . . )
                 && dt.TestId == Id
                 select dt).Count();
```

I saw this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335241/sql-not-in-in-linq-issue) and test the code.

```
int[] tempNotIn = new int[] { 13, 14, 15, 51, 52, 55, 59 };
int LeaveExists = (from dt in db.LeaveDetails join
             leavH in db.LeaveHeaders on dt.LeaveHeaderId equals leavH.LeaveHeaderId
             where !tempNotIn.Contains((int)leavH.LeaveTypeId) &&
             dt.TestId == Id
             select dt).Count();
```

it gives me an error `The name LeavH does not exist in the current context`.

`TestId` is `INT`

Comment: If the error message you gave is accurate, you have a typo, probably in the elided section. `LeaveH` is not equivalent to `leavH`

Comment: @DanielMann sorry got typo error. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all who view my post I got it. After a while of Trial and came up to this query and it's working

```
int[] tempNotIn = new int[] { 13, 14, 15, 51, 52, 55, 59 };
var LeaveExists = (from dt in db.LeaveDetails join
         leavH in db.LeaveHeaders on dt.LeaveHeaderId equals leavH.LeaveHeaderId
         where !tempNotIn.Contains((int)leavH.LeaveTypeId) &&
         dt.TestId == Id
         select dt).Count();
```